# Html forms in html table with JSP and servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Im coding an web app that requires me to fill a table with data of the employees of a company and users should be able to access this table and then click on a employee's name to go to their info page.

Im thinking of using forms (each clickable cell in table) to send the data to a servlet to process it and return the results, but im wondering if there is some other way of doing this without creating a form for each clickable cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A little client side scripting saves you. Just create a empty  form, take one `input` element.

on click of the table row get the user id, set the value to `input` submit the form.

Comment: well sure you can use some java script and ajax

Comment: Thanks! I created a js function to create a form with the input data from the row and it worked perfectly.